# Advice on which language to persue for browser automation & scraping

Tags: c#, asp.net, python, web2py, browser-automation

Novice to programming. I have most of my experience in python. I am comparind this to C#. I have created small web apps using Web2py, and have read 'learn python the hard way'. I have limited to no C# experience besides setting up and playing in VS.

My end goal is to be able to develop web apps (So far I do like web2py), and even some web automation programs using GUI's. For example, an application that will allow me to put / get information in a database from my GUI, and then post it to my site's either via a database connection, or post to other sites that are not mine, through automation.

I really like python so far, but I feel like since I do want to work with GUI applications, that C# may be the best bet...

More specifically, does Python even compare, or have modules/library that will help me do GUI web & browser automation, versus C#? How about with just basic scraping? Pulling data from numerous sites to display in a database. Does Python still have an edge?

Thanks. I hope this question has some objectivity to it considering the different libraries and modules available. If it is too subjective , please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is a pretty good library for automation if you want to scrape information off of javascript enabled pages.  It has bindings for a number of languages.  If you only want basic scraping though, I would go with Mechanize; no need to open a browser.